# Video not playing initially in Chrome

Tags: video, html5-video

I hope somebody can throw some light on this. This page has a background video http://www.metrocommercial.co.nz/, it plays fine in all browsers but in Chrome it doesn't play on initial page load (code has autoplay). If a duplicate version of the page loads in a new tab it does play = super annoying.

Here's the relevant code. The video file is 11MBs, which I'd have thought wasn't that big these days.

```
    <video class="img-responsive home-bg-video hidden-xs hidden-sm" autoplay loop poster="img/videoPoster.jpg">
        <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >            
    </video>
```

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, adding 'muted' to the attributes sorted things for  Chrome. Don't know why this has helped, but it has. So the video tag is as follows

```
<video class="bla" loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoPoster.jpg">
    <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" >   
</video>
```